# Add database parameters to NLog programmatically

Tags: c#, nlog

I want to log message to my database by NLog. Suppose I have the database ready.

```
    var dbTarget = new DatabaseTarget();
    dbTarget.Name = "test";
    dbTarget.ConnectionString = loggerModel.connection_string; 
    dbTarget.CommandText = "insert into NlogLogTable(LogDate,LogLevel,LogLogger,LogMessage,LogMachineName,LogUserName,LogCallSite,LogThreadId,LogThreadName,LogException,LogStackTrace) values(@LogDate,@LogLevel,@LogLogger,@LogMessage,@LogMachineName,@LogUserName,@LogCallSite,@LogThreadId,@LogThreadName,@LogException,@LogStackTrace);";
    var dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    var dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString();
    dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@LogDate", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${LogDate}")));
    dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@LogLevel", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${LogLevel}")));
    dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@LogLogger", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${LogLogger}")));
    dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@LogMessage", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${LogMessage}")));
    dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@LogMachineName", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${LogMachineName}")));
    dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@LogUserName", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${LogUserName}")));
    dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@LogCallSite", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${LogCallSite}")));
    dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@LogThreadId", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${LogThreadId}")));
    dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@LogThreadName", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${LogThreadName}")));
    dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@LogException", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${LogException}")));
    dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@LogStackTrace", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${LogStackTrace}")));
```

The thing is that I don't know how to pass the parameters to it. Let's say `LogDate` is today's datetime. Also I have **command timeout** (milliseconds) value, I am not sure how to pass it as well.

Answer (score 3):

There are various options to pass `LogDate` and other custom values.

1. Use the `${event-properties:LogDate}` and add the properties to your logEvent. (see [EventProperties-Layout-Renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer).
2. Use the `${date}` layout renderer, like `${date:format=yyyyMMdd}`
3. Use the `${mdc:item=String}` or `${gdc:item=String}`

For the **command timeout** you can use 2. or 3.

All possible values are listed on [the NLog wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers).

edit: the code for **command timeout**

Add to the target:

```
dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@LogDate", new NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout("${event-properties:CommandTimeout}")));
```

When writing the event (using the fluent interface, see [3](http://nlog-project.org/2015/01/20/have-you-seen-our-new-fluent-interface.html))

```
var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Info()
    .Message("This is a test fluent message '{0}'.", DateTime.Now.Ticks)
    .Property("CommandTimeout", YourCommandTimeout)
    .Write();
```

Comment: I need the precise code for `command timeout` in C#. Please use C# instead of script.

Comment: Thank you, the idea is impressive. However my `command timeout` is referring to [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property. Say 100 milliseconds.